# rails DB heroku migration error after column drop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, database-migration

I have problem to migrate my DB on my heroku app after my drop of my  column "type"

```
class RemoveTypeFromMandats < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
def change
remove_column :mandats, :type, :boolean
end
end
```

I drop this column because i did a mistake with the name,
a column cant be named "type"

But now when i try to migrate my DB on heroku i have this error

```
D, [2017-03-13T08:39:10.619658 #4] DEBUG -- :    (3.9ms)  ALTER TABLE      "mandats" DROP "type"
D, [2017-03-13T08:39:10.623526 #4] DEBUG -- :    (3.5ms)  ROLLBACK
D, [2017-03-13T08:39:10.627178 #4] DEBUG -- :    (3.3ms)  SELECT   pg_advisory_unlock(157042690317842070)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations  canceled:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "type" of relation "mandats" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "mandats" DROP "type"
```

Comment: There is no column exists name like `type` and you ran remove_column of that column

Comment: So i must delete the migration ?

Comment: `column_exists? `you can use on that migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [column_exists?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/column_exists%3F)

```
class RemoveTypeFromMandats < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    if column_exists? :mandats, :type         
      remove_column :mandats, :type, :boolean
    end
  end
end
```